# Emoji reading discrepancy between different applications

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I have a bunch of tweets/threads dataset that I need to process, along with some separate annotation files. These annotation files consists of some spans represented by indexes that corresponds to a word/sentence. The indexes are, as you may have predicted, the position of the characters in the tweet/thread files.

The problem arises when I process the files with some emojis in them. To go with a specific example:

This is a part of the file in question ([download](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bozmen/1c088af40c421ce307886cd8443d2993/raw/13fb17209deebc73e1a4ad1c6b07df29b9e511ea/028_948124816611139589.branch318.txt.username_text_tabseparated)):

```
TeamKhabib   @danawhite @seanshelby @arielhelwani @AliAbdelaziz00 #McTapper xxxxx://x.xx/xxxxxxxxxx
mmafan1709  @TeamKhabib @danawhite @seanshelby @arielhelwani @AliAbdelaziz00 Conor is Khabib hardest fight and Khabib is Conors hardest fight
```

I read the file in python with plain open function, with the parameter encoding='utf8':

```
with open('028_948124816611139589.branch318.txt.username_text_tabseparated', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read()
    print(content[211:214])
```

An annotation says there is the word `and` in the span 211-214. The way I read it I mention above, there is **' kh'**.

When I use the indexes in the annotation files to get the spanned string, the string I am getting is 3 chars off (to the right). Because, in the annotations, 's apparently take 2 spaces. However, when python reads them, it is one, hence the character shift. It becomes much more obvious when I get the length of the file with `len(list(file.read()))`. This returns me 7809, while the actual length of the file is 7812. 7812 is the pos I am getting at the end of the file in vscode, a plugin called vscode-position. Another file with gives me an inconsistency of 513 and 527.

I have no problem with reading emojis, I see them in my output/array however the space they are taking up in the encoding is different. My question is not answered in other relevant questions.

Obviously, there is a point in reading this file, as these files were read/created with some format/method/concept/encoding/whatever that this plugin and the annotators agree, but open.read does not.

I am using python 3.8.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Text is saved as an encoding of Unicode codepoints to bytes.   is a single codepoint, but encodes to 3 bytes in UTF-8 encoding.  The length of the Unicode string in Python is codepoints and the length of the file is bytes, so there will be a difference.  If your annotation files are byte indices, you may have to read the file as binary (`'rb'`) and then decode manually.

Comment: @MarkTolonen hmmm. Just as you said, I think 7812 is the byte offset and 7809 is a codepoint. however reading them with 'rb' and then applying decode('utf8') does not make any difference.

Comment: No, read the file in binary, fetch the bytes at a particular offset, *then* decode. Post a real example text with appropriate annotations and code that shows your problem if you want a solution.

Comment: @MarkTolonen that did not work too. I was wrong assuming that it was the byte offset, in fact the file is 7856 bytes. I got 6 chars off to the left by doing that. And just added the file to the question.

Comment: Not really useful without the annotations that go with it.  I'll post an example of what I'm talking about as an answer.

Comment: How are you processing the file?  That file is 55K+ bytes long and the first 'and' is 6585 bytes into the file

Comment: Post a [mcve] that gives the numbers you quote.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I added a google colab link.

Comment: @MarkTolonen and when I download the gist as a zip and extract it, it is ~250 bytes, not really 55k+.

Comment: Yes, I realized I downloaded it incorrectly.  I think when then spans were computed the file was saved as UTF-8 w/ BOM, but now it is not.  The UTF-8-encoded BOM is 3 extra characters.  The offsets are codepoint spans, but they are off by 3 bytes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen is that extra 3 characters constant? I have another file that has 14 bytes difference, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Since the data varies by more than 3 in other files, I think the answer is the spans were computed against Unicode strings that used surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue after discussion is the spans were computed from Unicode strings that used surrogate pairs for Unicode code points > U+FFFF.  Python 2 and other languages like Java and C# store Unicode strings with UTF-16 code units instead of abstracted code points like Python 3.  If I treat the test data as UTF-16LE-encoded, the answer comes out:

```py
import re

# Important to note that the original file has two tabs in it that SO doesn't display.
#  * Between the first "TeamKabib" and smiley
#  * Between "mmafan1709" and "@TeamKhabib"
# Use the download link while it is valid.

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read()
    b = content.encode('utf-16le')
    print(b[211 * 2:214 * 2].decode('utf-16le'))

# result: and
```

The offsets need to be double because each UTF-16 code unit is two bytes, then the result must be decoded to display it correctly.

I specifically used `utf-16le` vs. `utf-16` because the latter will add a BOM and throw off the count another two bytes (or one code unit).

Comment: Thıs seems to work great! Thank you for your time!